# How do we set a dictionary using reflection if we don't know the type arguments during compile-time?

Tags: c#, reflection

We have a dictionary in some unknown class, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue> MyDictionary` and we have the `FieldInfo` object obtained using reflection. We also have the type arguments `Type keyType = typeof(TKey)` and `Type valueType = typeof(TValue)` which are obtained during runtime.

The key-value pairs are present in two separate lists `List<object> keys` and `List<object> values`.

How do we generate the dictionary and set its value using `FieldInfo.SetValue()`?

So far, we tried this:

```
var dictionary = Activator.CreateInstance(fieldInfo.FieldType);
var keys = new List<object>();
var values = new List<object>();
// Code to set keys and values
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
   (dictionary as IDictionary).Add(keys[i], values[i]);

fieldInfo.SetValue(mainObj, dictionary);
```

In specific case where `TValue` is `List<int>`, the add statement throws an exception

> System.ArgumentException: 'The value "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" is not of type "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

Comment: You have `var values = new List<object>();`, so when you do `values[i]` it is returning an `object` typed object, which can't be inserted into a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` where `TValue` is `List` (instead of `object`). You'll have to change `values[i]` into a `List` typed object.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `TValue` could be anything, not just a list. So wondering if there is a general way to handle it.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? If you find yourself using a bunch of reflection you might want to take a step back and consider if it is really the best way to do it. Reflection tend to require more reflection, so it is best used in small amounts to solve very specific problems.

Comment: I would be very insightful to know A) a small example of fake data you are trying to compile. B) your motivation for compiling this data C) the reason you chose for reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, having types and values, for instance

```
// Let me use predefined types;
// You can obtain required types from FieldInfo
Type keyType = typeof(int);
Type valueType = typeof(string);

List<object> keys = new () {
    4, 5, 6
};

List<object> values = new () {
    "four", "five", "six"
};
```

you can

1. Create dictionary *type*
2. Create dictionary *instance*
3. Fill dictionary with *data*

```
var dictType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType);

var dictionary = Activator.CreateInstance(dictType);

for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; ++i)
    (dictionary as System.Collections.IDictionary).Add(keys[i], values[i]);
```

Let's have a look:

```
// Dictionary Type
Console.WriteLine(dictionary.GetType()); 
        
// Values
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                              (dictionary as IDictionary<int, string>)));
```

Output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]
[4, four]
[5, five]
[6, six]
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LmkPxO)

**Edit:** To obtain key and value type from `unknownDictionary`:

```
object unknownDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

...

Type keyType = unknownDictionary.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
Type valueType = unknownDictionary.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[1];
```

Comment: Could you check if your method works when the value type is a `list<string>` (so that the list `values` will be a `list<list<string>>`?

Comment: @Arvind Ganesh: Yes, it works; please, fiddle yourself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LmkPxO

Comment: This is cool, thanks a lot, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You have `var values = new List<object>();`, so `values[i]` is an `object` typed object, which can't be inserted into a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` where `TValue` is `List`.

You'll have to change `values[i]` into a `List` typed object. Try looking into [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype) and see if that can work (but the object must implement `IConvertible`).

By the way, I agree with what JonasH said in the comments on the question; reflection can be a recursive hole of more and more reflection to 'solve' the problem of reflection, so you might want to consider if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).